# Paging through Cassandra using QueryBuilder

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-java-driver

The [DataStax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) says that to page through all data, the following CQL query is useful:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE token(k) > token(42);
```

Is it possible to build this query using the `QueryBuilder`? It provides a [`token`](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#token(java.lang.String)) method, but that seems to work only on column names, not on values.

Ideally, the value (in the example: 42) is of type `Object`, just like in the eq/gte/lte functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using automatic paging with the .fetchSize method. It uses token under the hood:

Automatic paging is introduced Cassandra 2.0. Automatic paging allows the developer to iterate on an entire ResultSet without having to care about its size: some extra rows are fetched as the client code iterate over the results while the old ones are dropped. The amount of rows that must be retrieved can be parameterized at query time. In the Java Driver this will looks like:

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM images");
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);
```

Source: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

Answer (score 0):

QueryBuilder.fcall("token", value) ;

can solve the problem！